# django-cms_text_ckeditor ошибка подгрузки статки с Amazon S3 static storage

Tags: django, ckeditor, static, django-cms, amazon-s3

После деплоя проекта на django + django-cms на сервак, с использованием amazon S3 (STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
), не подгружается статика под django-cms_text_ckeditor, в бандле ckeditor-a пытается подгрузить статику из локала, да и та не работает, понятное дело, все остальные статические файлы подгружаются с s3 ведра прекрасно. На локалхосте ckeditor бандл обращается к локальной статике, и работает, другие стат.файлы берутся с S3 ведра. Есть идеи как сделать чтобы бандл собирал статику через S3 или хотя-бы брал локальные файла на серве(как на локалхосте)? Ибо этот плагин только в админке и не так критично им грузить сервак.

Не работает с настройками ckeditor-a как и дефолтными,так и кастомными с подгруженным бандлом с оф.сайта ckeditor

Снизу ошибки в консоли и скрин запросов на эти файлы.

Гугление этого, естесственно, к успеху не привело, хотя времени было потрачено уйма.

Django==1.11.13
django-cms_text_ckeditor==3.6.0

```js
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://myproject.herokuapp.com/static/cms_modules/ckeditor/config.js?t=G87E”. config:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://myproject.herokuapp.com/static/cms_modules/ckeditor/skins/moonocolor/skin.js?t=G87E”. config:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://myproject.herokuapp.com/static/cms_modules/ckeditor/lang/en.js?t=G87E”. config:1
TypeError: c[a] is undefined
```

[image: Запросы на серваке]

Answer (score 0):

Если кому-то интересно, то мне помог этот костыль:

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME', 'example-app')
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
TEXT_CKEDITOR_BASE_PATH = 'https://%s/djangocms_text_ckeditor/ckeditor/' % AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN
```